# Use Drag and Drop between list boxes DataSource

Tags: winforms, drag-and-drop, listbox

I'm trying to achieve Drag and Drop using this [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2006/Drag-and-Drop-between-list-boxes-Beginner-s-Tutori)

So first of all I populate first like with `DataSource` like:

```
   var techListQuery = $"exec getEmployeeListMailing";
   var techList = db.GetTableBySQL(techListQuery);

    lstTechUnnotified.DataSource = techList;
    lstTechUnnotified.DisplayMember = "Abbreviation";
    lstTechUnnotified.ValueMember = "UserName";
```

Once I do it I have `Mouse_Down` Event for first list box, but problem starts when it try to remove item from first list:

```
 if (dde1 == DragDropEffects.All)
            {
                lstTechUnnotified.Items.RemoveAt(lstTechUnnotified.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y));
            }
```

I getting message:

> 'Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is
> set

What can I do to solve this? Regards

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You can't modify the ListBox items when it has a DataSource. Instead, remove the item from the data source, and re-set the DataSource property of the ListBox.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are not adding the item to the `Items` property. If you are using the `DataSource`, you must remove the item from the `DataSource` itself, i.e., from `techList`. Then you have to update the listbox by re-assigning the data source

```
techList.RemoveAt(lstTechUnnotified.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y));

// Update the listbox
lstTechUnnotified.DataSource = null; // This is necessary, otherwise the LB donesn't notice
                                     // the change.
lstTechUnnotified.DataSource = techList;
```

If you are using a `BindingList`, updating the listbox is done automatically.

---

You might also have a look at my article [Drag-and-Drop ListBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36412/Drag-and-Drop-ListBox) at Code Project which describes advanced drag and drop techniques.